# ReactJS: Returning a React Component in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to loop through an array and return a React Component on each element. The render functions are being called but nothing is showing up.

```
class ListOfFoundPages extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderList = this._renderList.bind(this);
  }
  _renderList(data) {
    if (data !== null) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      data.list.map( (obj) => {
        return <ListItem obj={obj} />;
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="listOfFoundPages">
        {this._renderList(this.props.list)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the Component to be returned:

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div className="foundPagesItem">
        <img role="presentation" className="searchPageImg" src={props.obj.picture.data.url} />
        <span className="searchPageInfo">{props.obj.name} - {props.obj.category}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="seperator" />
    </li>
  );
};
export default ListItem;
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1785/

Answer (score 1):

`_renderList` function should return an array of components (the result of `data.list.map...`). Currently, it doesn't return anything. The code needs to look like:

```
_renderList(data) {
  if (data !== null) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    return data.list.map( (obj) => {
      return <ListItem obj={obj} />;
    });
  }
}
```